# IIS 301 redirect partial match

Tags: iis, url-rewrite-module

I have this rule:

```
<rule name="301 Redirect 1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/live-better/.*" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/business/live-better" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Which I want to work for the following:

- [www.test.com/live-better](http://www.test.com/live-better)
- [www.test.com/live-better/page-one](http://www.test.com/live-better/page-one)
- [www.test.com/live-better/page-two](http://www.test.com/live-better/page-two)

and I want them to all redirect to the counterpart:

- https://www.example.com/business/live-better
- https://www.example.com/business/live-better/page-one
- https://www.example.com/business/live-better/page-two

But my rule does not appear to work.
Does anyone know how I can get it to work?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules Enable FRT to see what actually happens under the hood. Your pattern for conditions is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try below rule:

```
    <rule name="301 Redirect 1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/live-better/(.*)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/business/live-better/{C:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```